# Interpretting Spark Stage Output Log

Tags: apache-spark, task, stage

When running a spark job on an AWS cluster I believe that I've changed my code properly to distribute both the data and the work of the algorithm I am using. But the output looks like this:

```
[Stage 3:>                                                       (0 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (1 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (2 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (3 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (4 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (5 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (6 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (7 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (8 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                       (9 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (10 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (11 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (12 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (13 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (14 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (15 + 2) / 1000]
[Stage 3:>                                                      (16 + 2) / 1000]
```

Am I correct to interpret the 0 + 2 / 1000 as only one two core processor carrying out one of the 1000 tasks at a time? With 5 nodes (10 processors) why wouldn't I see 0 + 10 / 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like the output I wanted:

```
[Stage 2:=======>                                             (143 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:=========>                                           (188 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:===========>                                         (225 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:==============>                                      (277 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:=================>                                   (326 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:==================>                                  (354 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:=====================>                               (405 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:========================>                            (464 + 21) / 1000]
[Stage 2:===========================>                         (526 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:===============================>                     (588 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:=================================>                   (633 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:====================================>                (687 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:=======================================>             (752 + 20) / 1000]
[Stage 2:===========================================>         (824 + 20) / 1000]
```

In AWS EMR make sure that the --executor-cores option is set to the number of nodes you are using like this:[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are total 1000 tasks to be completed. 2 cores are being used to complete the 1000 tasks. I am not sure about your setup (and never used AWS cluster) but I'd like you to check `spark.cores.max` in your spark configuration. This specifies the maximum number of cores to be used across all your executors. It would be also useful if you can show the contents of Executors tab of your job's spark UI

Comment: I'm not able to get into the UI, but I tried manually changing these in my java class:         conf.set("spark.cores.max", "infinite");
        
        conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true");

Comment: **@Aravind R. Yarram** & **@user1518003**, please do note that the said configuration `spark.cores.max` [does not work](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/configuration.html#scheduling) if `Spark` is run in `--deploy-mode cluster` with `--master yarn`